# Obj-C, need to find out if an imageview is inside another imageview?

Tags: objective-c

I'm just wondering if there's some methods which would make it simple to determine if an image view is inside another image view.

In my app theres several imageviews which can be dragged into another larger image view.

So far i think I'll have to check x and y co-ordinates against each object in a loop.

Just thought I'd ask

EDIT
The views will be on top of the larger view.
I need to evaluate locations rather than view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CGRectIntersectsRect` and/or `CGRectContainsRect` with the frames of your image views.

Comment: This will falsely return YES if innerView is located on top/bottom (!= inside) of outerView. Assuming that Jules is actually talking about "inside" and not "on top of".

Comment: What are goal and ball? And no need to check if it's equal to true. Just do `if (CGRectContainsRect(goal,ball)) {}`